# AWS lambda 250mb deployment package limit

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use bumpy, scipy.spare, scipy.optimise and cvxopt in AWS lambda, but there is an issue with the 250MB limit.

Scipy, Numpy and cvxopt only come out to about 175MB, but zipping and unzipping them brings them to around 325MB. Has anyone found a simple workaround for this?

If not, I can still try to split my code to only use 2 of the packages at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: How can zipping and unzipping them make their disk space increase?

Comment: because when they zip headers and stuff are included... I found it strange as well, but I haven't found a way around it yet.